# call global shortcut from command line

Tags: kubuntu, kde, plasma

Kubuntu 22.04

I need to start up chrome remotely connected through ssh.
I found out I can do this using dbus.

I created a global shortcut to start up google chrome.

I found the shortcut name in `qdbusviewer` :

```
google_chrome_desktop
```

From what I've read I need to invoke a dbus method with

```
qdbus org.kde.kglobalaccel /component/google_chrome_desktop
```

but more then that I cannot figure it out.
`/component/google_chrome_desktop` does not list any method like start, invoke or trigger.
Some old post about triggering a shortcut said `invokeShortcut` but I get `method does not exist`.

Can someone give me a hint?
Thanks you.

EDIT

I want to have a script which I can run when I'm connected over ssh to that computer, the script will start chrome on that computer,
chrome will be displayed on that computer.

I can execute google-chrome-stable from the terminal opened on the computer and chrome start without error.
If I try to execute the same when I'm connected over ssh
export DISPLAY=:0
google-chrome-stable
I get lots of errors(identity token, wallet, dbus,...) and I loose google authentication in chrome. I assume ssh terminal is not the same as konsole started in kde environment.
So I thought for a method to give kde the command to start chrome, hence dbus

Comment: Please clarify how you are connecting. You said you want to do this over ssh, does this mean you want to launch chrome on the _remote_ computer and have it displayed on your _local_ screen? Or do you want to launch chrome on the _remote_ computer and display it on the _remote_ screen? Or maybe something else? Why don't you just run `chrome` from the ssh terminal?

Comment: my computer remains running at home. I will connect over ssh and run a script that need to open google chrome on home computer.

Comment: So you want chrome to run on the remote computer _and_ be displayed on the remote computer? Please [edit] your question and clarify that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

with this I list the methods

```
 qdbus org.kde.kglobalaccel /component/google_chrome_desktop
    property read QString org.kde.kglobalaccel.Component.friendlyName
    property read QString org.kde.kglobalaccel.Component.uniqueName
    signal void org.kde.kglobalaccel.Component.globalShortcutPressed(QString componentUnique, QString shortcutUnique, qlonglong timestamp)
    signal void org.kde.kglobalaccel.Component.globalShortcutReleased(QString componentUnique, QString shortcutUnique, qlonglong timestamp)
    method {D-Bus type "a(ssssssaiai)"} org.kde.kglobalaccel.Component.allShortcutInfos()
    method {D-Bus type "a(ssssssaiai)"} org.kde.kglobalaccel.Component.allShortcutInfos(QString context)
    method bool org.kde.kglobalaccel.Component.cleanUp()
    method QStringList org.kde.kglobalaccel.Component.getShortcutContexts()
    method void org.kde.kglobalaccel.Component.invokeShortcut(QString shortcutName)
    method void org.kde.kglobalaccel.Component.invokeShortcut(QString shortcutName, QString context)
    method bool org.kde.kglobalaccel.Component.isActive()
    method QStringList org.kde.kglobalaccel.Component.shortcutNames()
    method QStringList org.kde.kglobalaccel.Component.shortcutNames(QString context)
    signal void org.freedesktop.DBus.Properties.PropertiesChanged(QString interface_name, QVariantMap changed_properties, QStringList invalidated_properties)
    method QDBusVariant org.freedesktop.DBus.Properties.Get(QString interface_name, QString property_name)
    method QVariantMap org.freedesktop.DBus.Properties.GetAll(QString interface_name)
    method void org.freedesktop.DBus.Properties.Set(QString interface_name, QString property_name, QDBusVariant value)
    method QString org.freedesktop.DBus.Introspectable.Introspect()
    method QString org.freedesktop.DBus.Peer.GetMachineId()
    method void org.freedesktop.DBus.Peer.Ping()
```

with this I get the shortcut names for google-chrome

```
qdbus org.kde.kglobalaccel /component/google_chrome_desktop org.kde.kglobalaccel.Component.shortcutNames
    _launch
    new-window
    new-private-window
```

and with this I launch google chrome

```
qdbus org.kde.kglobalaccel /component/google_chrome_desktop org.kde.kglobalaccel.Component.invokeShortcut "_launch"
```